# SocketIO connection stop sending data after 4-5 hours

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, reactjs

I have developed an application with ReactJS, ExpressJS, MongoDB and SocketIO.

I have two servers:- **Server A** || **Server B**

Socket Server is hosted on the **Server A** and application is hosted on the **Server B**

I am using **Server A** socket on **Server B** as a client.

Mainly work of **Server A** socket is to emit the data after fetching from the MongoDB database of **Server A**

Everything is working as expected but after 4-5-6 hours stop emitting the data but the socket connection will work.

I have checked using

```
socket.on('connection',function(){
 console.log("Connected")
)
```

I am not getting whats the wrong with the code.

My code : https://jsfiddle.net/ymqxo31d/

Can anyone help me out on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some programming errors.

I am getting data from MongoDB inside the setInterval() so after a little while exhausts resources and database connection starts failing every time.

Firstly i have created a Single MongoDB connection and used every place where i needed.

2ndly i removed setInterval and used setTimeout as below. *(**NOTE:** If i continue using setInterval it execute on defined interval. It doesn't have any status that the data is emitted or not [this also cause the heavy resource usages] but i need to emit the data to socket when successfully fetched.)*

```
setTimeout(emitData,1000);
function emitData(){
     db.collection.find({}).toArray(function(data){
         socket.emit('updateData',data);
         setTimeout(emitData,1000);
     })
}
```